# Broker vs. SQLPLUS to manage Data Guard configuration

Tags: oracle

Can anyone tell me the link to the comparison between using SQLPLUS and Data Guard Broker to manage data guard configuration?
Advantages and disadvantages of those two command line interfaces?

Thanks,

Sarith

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of using SQL*Plus is it requires you to have a full understanding of what's going on "behind the scenes". I would recommend setting up a DG configuration manually at least once, for your own education. Trust me, you'll learn a lot. The broker has the advantage of providing shortcuts to the functions you might need to perform with your DG configuration, and is probably your best option (short of Grid Control, with which you can create a standby, monitor status, switchover, failover with a few mouse clicks) for a production environment.

If you use SQL*Plus to manage it, you'll likely develop scripts that duplicate some broker functionality anyway.